# Linear Equation With Constraints

Tags: real-analysis, linear-programming

Imagine this problem: You have several batteries. Each battery has $4$ variables:

1. Minimum number of modules in series;
2. Maximum number of modules in series;
3. Maximum number of modules you can connect totally;
4. Number of connections;

And, the number of connections determines the number of different series you can have. For example: If the battery has only $1$ connection, you can't connect series of $18$ modules and $19$ modules. You can only connect $N$ series of $18$ or $19$.

Example of an acceptable arrangement:

[image: SEE IMAGE HERE]

**Real Example:**

Let's say we want to discover if a battery can hold $91$ modules. And these are the specifications of the battery:

- $2$ connections
- Minimum number of modules in series: $16$
- Maximum number of modules in series: $20$
- Maximum number of modules: $132$

For what a undestand, I can draw this equation: $16a + 17b + 18c + 19d + 20e = 91$, where $a, b, c, d$ and $e$ are positives and integers numbers.

And, if I have at least one solution to this equation, I can assume that this battery can hold $91$ modules.

But, the main probleam is: Since the battery has $2$ connections, only $1$ or $2$ variables (of $a, b, c, d$ and $e$) can be different from zero.

So, it's true that $(16 \times 1) + (17 \times 0) + (18 \times 2) + (19 \times 1) + (20 \times 1) = 91$, but this is not a valid answer. Because it has $1$ series of $16$, $2$ series of $18, 1$ series of $19$ and $1$ series of $20$. $4$ different series, but the battery accepts maximum of $2$.

And, I don't have a clue how to pass this problem.

I thought of arranging the variables with repetition (combinatorial analysis) and than solve the equation for each combination. But, I need to replicate this on Microsfot Excel and this method would take hours to process.

Comment: @lovsovs i tried to draw it. I think it is difficult to understand because english is not my native language. But thank you nonetheless